# Get value from nested paragraph to execute conditional

Tags: paragraph, drupal-9

I have a [Paragraph](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) nested in another Paragraph as per attached screenshot in Drupal 9. I want to write a conditional for `my_repeater_2` that's based off the value of the `my_dropdown` field in `my_repeater_1`.

The keys|values in `my_dropdown` are:

```
1|25:75
2|50:50
```

I have a  template `field--paragraph--my-repeater-1.html.twig` with the following and it outputs 1 or 2 depending on the dropdown selection.

```
 {% for item in items %}
        {{ item.content }}
    {% endfor %}
```

I also have a template `paragraph--my_fields.html.twig` with:

```
   {%
      set classes = [
        'paragraph',
        'paragraph--type--' ~ paragraph.bundle|clean_class,
        view_mode ? 'paragraph--view-mode--' ~ view_mode|clean_class,
        not paragraph.isPublished() ? 'paragraph--unpublished'
      ]
    %}
{% block paragraph %} 
  {% block content %} 
      {% if content.my_dropdown.0 == "1" %}
         DO X
      {% endif %}
      {% if content.my_dropdown.0 == "2" %}
         DO Y
     {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}
{% endblock paragraph %}
```

How do I retrieve the value from the `my_dropdown` field in `my_repeater_1`, as `content.my_dropdown.0` doesn't work, so my IF conditional can process. I've tried every variation at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/274359/get-pre-processed-data-from-nested-paragraphs. Must be something easy?

[image]

Comment: solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52312728/accessing-the-referencing-parent-element-in-twig-paragraphs

Comment: "You can only post once every 30 minutes." - so annoying